# How to switch the keyboard light on?

Tags: keyboard

I have a Dell e6420. The keyboard light is not working with elementary OS. How is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn keyboard lights on in the terminal by typing `xset led 3`.

Turn them off with: `xset led off`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you recommend `xset led 3` instead of `xset led on`?